# how to add content security policy (CSP) to nginxinc ingress controller or ingress rule

Tags: kubernetes, content-security-policy, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

How to add content security policy (CSP) to **nginxinc ingress controller** or ingress rule.

I tried both of the below annotation to ingress rule but neither worked.

```
annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' 'none' ;";
      add_header Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'none' ;
```

Comment: This works. Your `more_set_headers` is not valid definitions as attempt to specify two headers there (`Content-Security-Policy` and `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only`

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
    more_set_headers "Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: your-policy";
```

Remember to modify `your-policy` to something real ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The solution from fandasson works, but the 'configuration-snippet' annotation is disabled by default since Ingress-NGINX version 1.9.0.

If you're using the [nginx-ingress Helm chart](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/charts/ingress-nginx), this means setting:

```
controller:
  allowSnippetAnnotations: true
```

Enabling it has security implications for multi-tenant clusters, see:

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet